# How it works; "executeUpdate()"?

Tags: jdbc

I am new to JDBC and just for the testing purpose I passed **Select queries** in **executeUpdate()** instead of **DML queries**; and the result I got, made me so confused.

I tested it on Scott user's tables of oracle 11g.

For **dept** and **salgrade** table it returns integer no. **4** and **5** which are the no. of records in these tables I think. 
And for **emp** table it should return 14, but it **returned 10**; why ?

My code is:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JdbcTest2
{

public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","scott","tiger");

        Statement st=con.createStatement();

        System.out.println(st.executeUpdate("select * from dept"));
        System.out.println(st.executeUpdate("select * from salgrade"));
        System.out.println(st.executeUpdate("select * from emp"));

        st.close();
        con.close();

    }
}
```

I know that executeUpdate() is not meant for select queries; but what is happening here please explain me and let me to come out this confusion.**Thank You**

Comment: The result from using `executeUpdate()` for a select query is undefined. There is no sense in answering your question because your code is simply wrong.

Comment: Technically it is a bug in the driver, as it is supposed to throw an `SQLException` when _"the given SQL statement produces a ResultSet object"_ (see [`Statement.executeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-))